# VSTS/TFS Delivery plans

Tags: tfs

I'm testing delivery plans extension and i'm wondering if i can create delivery plans from teams belonging to different TFS collections. Per what i'm testing it can't be done, but just want make sure it's not a security set up.

Answer (score 0):

No, we can not create delivery plans cross different TFS collections.